# Apple push notification packets ignored

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm sending a packet to Apple for a push notification, but it never shows up on my device, nor does the Feedback service report any errors.  The packet looks like this.  Does anybody see what's wrong here?  If I much with the packet I get an error back, so I know I'm successfully talking to the sandbox.  If I gave an invalid token, it would tell me that too.

```
# php send.php | xxd<br/>
0000000: 0100 0000 0151 09d1 af00 2070 d7d9 0472  .....Q.... p...r
0000010: 443b f4c5 cd59 d581 dc3c 3da9 ee68 413e  D;...Y...<=..hA>
0000020: 8a9f 2566 285e 354e 9b26 ae00 367b 2261  ..%f(^5N.&..6{"a
0000030: 7073 222c 7b22 616c 6572 7422 3a22 5365  ps",{"alert":"Se
0000040: 6e74 2030 363a 3036 3a33 3920 504d 222c  nt 06:06:39 PM",
0000050: 2273 6f75 6e64 223a 2264 6566 6175 6c74  "sound":"default
0000060: 227d 7d                                  "}}<br/>
```

I'm creating the packet like so, from PHP:

```
pack('CNNnH*', 1, $id++, $expiration, 32, $token) . pack('n', $messageLength) . $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if Apple sees an error, it will close the socket connection with your server. If you're using *fwrite*, make sure you have a catch for fwrite failing or fwrite's length being less than the length of your apns message. Does your connection fail after sending the data to Apple? If yes, then the payload format is definitely wrong.

There are two ways of sending push notifications. Since I see an *$expiration* property, I'm assuming you're using the binary method which has a slightly different payload. Make sure you use the right payload format depending on the method you're using. I would recommend you first try using the non-binary method (as it's simpler) and then move on to the binary method.